# Loading a default option in a select with angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to put a default option in my select that comes from a service.

My Select.

```
<select (change)="changeValue()" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
<option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">{{ item.article }} - {{ item.value }}</option>
</select>
```

The array that I am passing to the `ngFor`.

```
  items: Array<any> = 
  [{ article: 'item1', value: 10 },{ article: 'item2', value: 20 }]
```

When I load this component in my app, I receive from the database an object that contains one of these options.

So what I would like to do is, the option that I receive, set it as default.

I tried with `[selected]` but it is not working. How can I do it?

Comment: check this also:https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you have this things missing:

1. `ngValue` should be item.value
2. You already assingning values so just changing the selectedValue variable would work, just like I did inside `ngOnInit`

Try something like this:

Typescript end:

```
  items: Array<any> =
    [{ article: 'item1', value: 10 }, { article: 'item2', value: 20, defaultSelected: true }];
  selectedValue: string = '';
  ngOnInit() {      
    this.selectedValue = this.items.filter(a => a.defaultSelected)[0].value;
  }
```

HTML end:

```
<select (change)="changeValue()" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
<option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item.value">{{ item.article }} - {{ item.value }}</option>
</select>
```

Please check this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v2a81r

Comment: sorry maybe i didnt explain it well... i forked your demo... and i added some comments... please check it out. because i dont understand what you did :S
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ehzbx?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @SergioCano as option value attribute can not store whole object, So I used `item.value` instead of `item` now as `item.value` is the value of the `select` You need to assign `item.value` to the `this.selectedValue` same as I did in my demo.

Comment: `selectedValue: Object = { article: 'item1', value: 10 };` should be string instead of object `selectedValue: string = "10";`

Comment: ok i got it, yea...what i didnt undestand is that the option cant store all the object... thanks for you help

Answer (score 2):

A non `ngModel` way of doing it is as below, as `ngModel` is deprecated in v7: https://next.angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel

```
<select (change)="changeValue()" [value]="defaultValue">
<option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.value">{{ item.article }} - {{ item.value }}</option>
</select>
```

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvnjn5

Comment: is nice to know that ngModel will be deprecated in v7, but how do you bind the new value to defaultValue?

Comment: Just set the `defaultValue` again, check my updated demo. After 3 sec the selected value would change.

Comment: i mean, if you change the option using the select box... how do you bind it to a variable... i always did it with [(ngModel)]

Comment: You would need reference variable for the same, updated my demo. There is another way to get it in reactive forms, which I would suggest you to explore :)