# My default option don't show in my select

Tags: html, angular

I have one select, but the default option "Primeiro filtro" don't show:

[image]

My template:

```
<div class="select">

  <select [(ngModel)]="controlaRadios" name="tipoDoProdutoName" class="select-text">
    <option class="dropdown-item" disabled selected value>Primeiro filtro</option>
    <option value="1" class="dropdown-item">Todos</option>
    <option value="2" class="dropdown-item">Tipo de anúncio</option>
  </select>

  <span class="select-highlight"></span>
  <span class="select-bar"></span>

</div>
```

TS:

```
controlaRadios: any = "Primeiro filtro"
```

Comment: You can try and set `selected="selected"` in the option tag which you want to be default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading a default option in a select with angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52846694/loading-a-default-option-in-a-select-with-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Hope it will work for you :)

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="controlaRadios" name="tipoDoProdutoName" class="select-text">
    <option value="Primeiro filtro" class="dropdown-item">Primeiro filtro</option>
    <option value="1" class="dropdown-item">Todos</option>
    <option value="2" class="dropdown-item">Tipo de anúncio</option>
  </select>

  <span class="select-highlight"></span>
  <span class="select-bar"></span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look here and try to adapt. Hope this helps.

.html

```
<select class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedType">
        <option *ngFor="let type of types" [ngValue]="type">{{type}}</option>
</select>
```

.ts

```
types: Array<Object> = ['Default option', 'First option', 'Second option']
selectedType = this.types[0];
```

Comment: @Tenzolinho seems like you forgot to save your stackblitz